Movie about a boy who is mistaken for a couple's dead son
I'm trying to think of a movie where a boy, who sort of looks like Sean Faris, meets this blonde girl. The boy and girl sneak into houses for fun, but on one of these occasions they are caught by a couple. The couple realized, he looks like their son and they keep him there and torture him until he says that he is their son. One form of torture; he is tied up to a chair and his eyes are forced open so he can watch a movie that was their son's favorite. When he tries to escape the couple think he's dead and they bury him in their backyard and cover him with flowers. In the end, the blonde comes back and finally saves him.
Year: Possibly 2008, maybe earlier.
Country: I think it's American.

Hi. Do you remember the approximate year? Was it American?

I want to say around 2008 maybe earlier. I think it's american

Sounds like Inside fom 2006.

Friends Alex and Josie have a disturbing hobby. They like to follow strangers. One night Alex takes things too far when he sneaks into a home and gets caught...instead of calling the police, the couple, fascinated by his resemblance to their dead son Timmy, ask him to stay. As the grieving couple begins to believe that Alex really is Timmy, he finds himself trapped in a horrifying existence of desperation, despair, and insanity-and Josie, suspicious of Alex's sudden disappearance, is his only chance at escape...

They eventually bury him in their back yard, but Josie (Leighton Meester) arrives and digs him up. Here's the trailer:




Omg thank you! It was driving me nuts!
